# Fetch comments from LinkedIn Live Video Posts

Tags: linkedin-api

We are developing application which will allow user to live stream on LinkedIn. For that purpose, we created app and added product "Live Events". With live events API, we are able to create event and stream live.
Along with streaming, we would like like to fetch the comments from the live video post.

For that, we are not able to find API. Also we can not add another products like "Community Management API" which supports comments API.
Please let us know way to fetch comments using "Live Events" APIs.